# Need 64-bit SQLite DLL for managed C# application

Tags: c#, sqlite, managed, badimageformatexception

I'm trying to embed SQLite into my portable C# .NET 2.0 application rather than having the DLL files included in the distribution folder. However, to embed SQLite, I cannot use the Mixed-Mode libraries provided by PHXSoftware. Instead, I am using their 'Managed Only' version.

This works fine on 32-bit computers, but when it's running on a 64-bit machine, it throws a format exception. As I found out from here: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2564/9939.aspx I need to load the unmanaged sqlite3.dll manually in the required architecture format first before I use the managed libraries.

That's where I fall short. I cannot find a 64-bit version of SQLite to include along with the 32-bit one. Can anyone help? Dare I say, does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you build the source yourself. It's very straight-forward to do. Especially considering Sqlite offers [amalgamation source](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html).

Here are the compiler pre-processor defines I use for a 64-bit release build:

- WIN64 NDEBUG
- _WINDOWS
- _USRDLL
- NO_TCL
- _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
- THREADSAFE=1
- TEMP_STORE=1
- SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH=0

Here are the compiler pre-processor defines I use for a 32-bit release build:

- WIN32
- NDEBUG
- _WINDOWS
- _USRDLL
- NO_TCL
- _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
- THREADSAFE=1
- TEMP_STORE=1
- SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH=0

Comment: Can you advise on where to put these defines? I'm compiling this from my Linux VM using the autoconf amalgamation.

Comment: Sorry, I naively assumed you were on Windows (my bad). I can't help you with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) fork has x86/x64 binaries for .Net 2, 3.5, and 4. Downloads are [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

**Update:**

Another possible solution is to target your application for x86 platform and just use the x86 SQLite libraries. If your application doesn't require x64 features targeting the x86 platform will greatly reduce the complexity of your deployment.

Comment: Unfortunately it does require x64 =[

Comment: Plus, these binaries appear to only include System.Data.SQLite with sqlite3 embedded. I need the sqlite3.dll file by itself.